# Append method to button created in other method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

It is possible add method to event onclik. This code create event onclick in html "onclick='alert("TEST");undefined'". I care to get "onclick='alert("TEST");stdaction('t1')'" where stdaction('t1') is function in class Button

```
function Button(id,onclick){
        this.id = id;
        this.onclick= onclick;
    }

Button.prototype.create = function(){
    var button = $('<div>');
    button.attr('id',this.id);
    button.html('Default');
    button.attr('onclick',this.onclick+';'+this.stdaction(this.id)); // this is problem
    return button.prop('outerHTML');
}

Button.prototype.stdaction = function(id){
    $('#'+id).addClass('std-active');
}
var oneButton = new Button('t1','alert("TEST")');
$('#newButton').append(oneButton.create());
```

I changed as suggested Paflow is better, but I wanted to make a function connected running the onclick even had a separate method
https://jsfiddle.net/uevckbe0/

Comment: Enclose `this.stdaction(this.id)` in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
   button.attr('onclick',this.onclick+';'+this.stdaction(this.id)); // this is problem
```

write something like

```
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.onclick();
     this.stdaction(this.id)
  }.bind(button));
```

Comment: This is a partial solution, because the console returns "this.stdaction is not a function" I changed to create a div element with jquery to javascript and move the definition of Button.prototype.stdaction to button.addEventListener will work, wanted to me to connect Button.prototype.stdaction the declaration of the event was spun off https://jsfiddle.net/uevckbe0/

Comment: I have no Idea what stdaction is, it is not defined in your code, so I did't define it either.